# Flask - wait until disk is mounted

Tags: flask

I am trying to move my console app to Flask but I am new to this framework.
What I first need to do is to launch the application and show a "waiting" page until a disk is mounted. When the mount succeeds, the application should redirect to the main index page.

Any clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a waiting page to user at first. And you can do ajax request to your Flask server to polling the status of your task(mount disk). When you get disk mounted in ajax response, You can redirect to main index page.

Or you can use websocket to inform the status of your task. There is a extension named `Flask-SocketIO` implement websocket for you.

Comment: Something like this main app?
 `code`
 check = checkifmounted()
 if (check=False):
  return render_template('wait.html')
 else:
  return render_template('index.html')
  `code`

and then, in the template "wait" should I run jQuery/Ajax?